# Why does icenReg or survival's "interval2" not accept event indicator?

Tags: r, survival, interval-censoring

In "normal" survival analysis that I'm familiar with (probably because they're very common), such as logistic regression, Cox PH, decision trees, the time to event analysis always includes an indicator of the outcome variable.

How come there is no implementation of interval-censored analysis (at least in R) that takes the outcome variable into account? And why does the `survival`'s "interval2" not take the outcome indicator into account?

[image]

How can one implement icenReg's methods to a dataset that looks like this? Should the right side of the interval be replaced by Inf when the event didn't take place? In my dataset, the event occurs only 1.3% of all rows- that means 98.7% of intervals will end with Inf- that is surely a huge loss of information?

I feel like I'm missing something very important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page for the `Surv()` function:

> think of each observation as a time interval with (-infinity, t2) for left censored, (t1, infinity) for right censored, (t,t) for exact and (t1, t2) for an interval. This is the approach used for type = interval2. Infinite values can be represented either by actual infinity (Inf) or NA.

That provides a general-purpose format that can handle all forms of censoring. An event outcome is taken into account by the presence of finite values for both ends of a time interval. So yes, the right side of the interval should be replaced with `Inf` or `NA` if there is no event during the interval.

You have multiple rows for the same ID, which I suspect is part of what you're worried about. As the help page for the `ir_clustBoot()` function in the [`icenReg` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=icenReg) says:

> Standard models in icenReg assume independence between each observation. This assumption is broken if we can have multiple observations from a single subject, which can lead to an underestimation of the standard errors. ir_clustBoot addresses this by using a cluster bootstrap to fix up the standard errors.
>
> Note that this requires refitting the model bs_samples, which means this can be fairly time consuming.

So you provide the `ID` values to that bootstrapping function after you fit the initial model. You will have to consider whether the "working independence" assumption involved in estimating the regression coefficient values is reasonable, as only the standard error estimates are re-evaluated by that function. It might not be, for example, if a single individual can experience more than one event of the same type.

Comment: Thanks so much, EdM! I'm worried that, in my case, the event happens in less than 2% of all records, so 98% of events will be closing with Inf! indeed closing an interval with Inf means a loss of quite a lot of information? RE: independence, another way to fit the model would be to treat each event as truly separate- each new L would start from 0 and the new R would be the difference R-L from the table in the question. But icenReg (and Surv()) seem to dislike that too- do you know why?

Comment: @Wojty the information in a survival model is primarily in the events. Are these really interval=censored observations, or counting-process data (with left _truncation_)? See [_Interval-Censored Time-To-Event Data : Methods and Applications_](https://doi.org/10.1201/b12290), Chen _et al._ eds., CRC Press (2012) for the difficulties of combining counting-process and interval-censored analysis. If you have time-varying covariates you might be better off with Bayesian joint modeling of covariate values and time-to-event. See the [survival task view](https://cran.r-project.org/view=Survival).

Comment: Thanks! I'll post a separate question wrt. intervals starting from 0. Before I accept your answer, could you please clarify a bit more why the Inf mark on the right side of the interval in so many rows isn't losing any information?

Comment: @Wojty `Inf` on the right side in that format just means right censoring as of the time indicated at the left side of the corresponding time-interval coding. Yes, right censoring does represent a loss of information over having exact or finite interval-censored event times, but it's no more a loss of information than you have with any right censoring. This is just a different way of writing the right censoring when you might also have interval-censored event times.

Comment: that's exactly my point- how do I tell IcenReg that an event hasn't occurred without masking it with the right censoring (Inf)? If I can't, that is surely a major limitation of the method?

Comment: @Wojty it's no more of a limitation than is representing a lack of an observed event with the 0-right-censored/1-event indicator in the usual `Surv(time, event}` format. Unlike that simple format, the `interval2` format _adds_ the possibility of encoding interval-censored observations. Handling of right censoring is the same in either encoding: a right-censored event time is one that is only known to occur _after_ some defined observation time. That means, in principle, the event could be at an infinite time.